# ServletSecurity annotation getting applied to all servlets added programatically. why?

Tags: servlets, security, servlet-3.0

As per Servlet 3.0 specifications - " @ServletSecurity annotation is not applied to the url-patterns of a ServletRegistration create using the addServlet(string, Servlet)  method of the Servletcontext interface, unless the servlet was constructed by the createServlet method of the ServletContext."

However while experimenting with it the ServletSecurity annotation is getting applied to all the servlets I'm adding in ServletContextListener.contextInitialized() method.

Listener code:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
    System.out.println(" ContextInitialized -- start");
    ServletContext ctx = e.getServletContext();
    try {

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic sr2 = ctx.addServlet("myServlet2", "com.example.web.MyServlet1");
    sr2.addMapping("/myServlet2");
    System.out.println("param2 added status : " + sr2.setInitParameter("param2", "value2"));
    sr2.setLoadOnStartup(3);

    Class<MyServlet1> myServletClass = (Class<MyServlet1>) Class.forName("com.example.web.MyServlet1");
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic sr3 = ctx.addServlet("myServlet3", myServletClass);
    sr3.addMapping("/myServlet3");
    sr3.setLoadOnStartup(2);

    System.out.println("param3 added status : " + sr3.setInitParameter("param3", "value3"));

    MyServlet1 myServlet4 = ctx.createServlet(myServletClass);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic sr4 = ctx.addServlet("myServlet4", myServlet4);
    sr4.addMapping("/myServlet4");
    sr4.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    System.out.println("param4 added status : " + sr4.setInitParameter("param4", "value4"));

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ServletException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(" ContextInitialized -- finish");

}
```

Annotation in the servlet:

```
@ServletSecurity (
    httpMethodConstraints = {
            @HttpMethodConstraint(
                value="GET",
                rolesAllowed = {"sme"},
                transportGuarantee = ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.NONE// CONFIDENTIAL             
            ),
            @HttpMethodConstraint(
                value="POST",
                rolesAllowed = {"ssme"},
                transportGuarantee = ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.NONE//CONFIDENTIAL              
            )
    }
)
```

It's asking authentication for all of them.

Any insights will be helpful.

Thanks
-Vineet

Answer (score 0):

The `@ServletSecurity annotation` is applied to all url patterns mapped to the servlet. It only excludes the servlet progrmatically added through `addServlet(..)` methods.

> ## Spec Says...........
>
> The @ServletSecurity annotation is not applied to the url-patterns of a 
>   ServletRegistration created using the addServlet(String, Servlet) 
>   method of the ServletContext interface, **unless the Servlet was constructed by 
>   the createServlet method of the ServletContext interface**.

Comment: So @ServletSecurity annotation should not apply to the "myServlet3" in above code and any request to url "/myServlet3" should be unconstrained. But it's not. What am i missing here?